# NS2 with RC4 and tcllib package

Tags: ns2

I have a fresh installation of NS-2.35 and I want to use RC4 in ns2.35 but not getting nay help regarding the proper installation. I din not find how to install tcllib package which provide rc4 package.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read about "RC4" ? A link, please.

RC usually means "Release Candidate" :  Like ns-allinone-2.35-RC4.tar.gz,

... which is a predecessor for ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz .

-

Comment: OKi when i search about the RC4 algortihm i found ns2_2.35~RC4-1.debian so i thought that it is for implementing RC4 for stream cipher implementing package.

Comment: Actually i want to implement RC4 stream cipher in NS2 have u any idea about it how to implment it in ns2.35??